# Should we allow [ui] tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Does it make sense to tag [ui] on a site such as **User Interface** Stack Exchange? I'm starting to see [more and more](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui) of those and was wondering if I was doing right in retagging.

My vote would be to eliminate/retag those. This is a UI site, so all topics should relate somehow to UI. And those who don't should be tagged accordingly or get closed. It's like tagging [programming] on SO or [cooking] on [Food & Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).

On the other hand, there are [44 questions](http://uxexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux) tagged [ux] on UXExchange :S

What's your take on this?

Comment: I must admit to having doubts about the benefits of a [ui] tag too.

Comment: UXExchange is different, since UX is an umbrella term, so if you post an umbrella question, it makes sense to tag it as such. However, you can also post specific questions about UI, design, etc on uxexchange.

Comment: General agreement here as well. Just as one wouldn't tag a post on bicycles.stack with [bicycle] or on tex.stack with [tex], it would make sense to not use the [ui] tag here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone with 200 rep should keep an eye on the tags and edit when there's a clear improvement to be made. I think we have a consensus that a UI tag is tautological, so go ahead and remove it when you see it. I edited the tag wiki to say so as well.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/ui/info

Answer (score 4):

I agree. It seems redundant.

Comment: And repetitive!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely should not be allowed. So are we actually going to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just saw another tag that we should really consider removing from the site - "interactive-ui". Calling something an "interactive user interface" is redundant and leaves us with just "user interface" which is the same tag that we're actively trying to clean up. I think it makes sense to do the same with this tag.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would agree with you on this. The way I can imagine it being useful is if the questions are somehow displayed on another website that isn't UI specific. Then(assuming the tags were carried over) it would be useful to know.

Comment: If content is copied it needs to be properly attributed (see the [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required) link at the foot of every page, so it should be obvious it's from a UI Q&A site

Comment: I'm not talking copying the content and sticking it on another page or anything like that.  But what if say SE put out an API and someone developed an app for using multiple SE sites at once.  Tags would probably be useful.

Comment: In that case you could identify which Q came from UI and which from SO programmaticaly, no need for [ui]. If that were the case, we should expect all SO questions to be tagged [programming].

Comment: Good point ign.