# Blacklisted tags - present and future

Tags: discussion, retagging

As previously covered at [Should we allow [ui] tags?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/should-we-allow-ui-tags) and [Why are a lot of the merged UXExchange questions tagged with "untagged"](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/why-are-a-lot-of-the-merged-uxexchange-questions-tagged-with-untagged), the [ui](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui) and [ux](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux) tags have gone away.

You may have noticed (especially if you've looked at the front page recently) that all the questions that had the [untagged](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag now have real tags instead.

**So, what's left?**

While re-tagging, I noticed that the site still has some variants of the [ui](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui) tag in use:

> [interactive-ui](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive-ui) [gui-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-design) [default-ui](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/default-ui) [broken-ui](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-ui) [user-interface](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface)

Do all of these tags still make sense? Some of them, but not others? Or?

If there's a consensus that any/all should go away, **please help out! All you'll need to do is**:

- Click on one of the tag links above
- Pick a question from the list that shows up
- Retag it: delete the unwanted tag and add new tags when needed
- Save your edits.

If you have [less than 200 rep](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions), your edit will have to be approved by other community members.

If you have [over 150 rep](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), you can create new tags.

And thanks for helping to make this site a better place!

Answer (score 5):

I believe that neither UX nor UI belong as tags. Tags that general are not really useful on a site like this. Every question should be at least one of them, and a large subset of questions are going to be both.

As for the other tags you have listed:

- **interactive-ui** I don't like it (what do you do with an interface other than interact with it?), but I most often see it used more in conjunction with Ajax-style web questions. Maybe a better name?
- **gui-design** I'm torn on this. In some ways, it is WAY too broad, because almost every question on here is relating to computer software/website interfaces (and as such, graphical by nature). However, if this site actually got a significant number of questions about non-computer screen interfaces, then it would be useful. Since I don't see it happening, I personally would get rid of this one.
- **default-ui** This one doesn't really make sense to me. Only one of the two questions tagged with it makes even the slightest amount of sense sense to have it. Might be too confusing to keep.
- **broken-ui** Makes absolutely no sense on the one question that is tagged with it. I say it goes.
- **user-interface** Needs to go. Either rolled into "ui" if we decide to keep that one, or just get rid of it entirely. UI *stands for* User Interface, so there's no reason to have both tags.

Comment: Agreed. Go ahead and retag as you see fit.

Comment: @Patrick - I've cleaned up a few of these, but they still show up in the tag list. Is that something that cleans itself up over time?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if there's a cron job to remove those tags or not. You can probably find out on meta.stackoverflow.com.